# Workaround to using pip in virtual python 2.7 32-bit environemnt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, conda, 32bit-64bit

I am currently using Anaconda to setup a virtual environment of python 2.7.1 32-Bit. My project require several packages to be downloaded.
However, when I try

```
>pip install numpy
```

It gives me the following error.

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:424: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  SNIMissingWarning,
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:164: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning,
```

I have noticed that this only happens for the 32-bit installation of Python and not in the 64 bit version. However, the [Melodia](https://github.com/justinsalamon/audio_to_midi_melodia) library I am trying to use require python 2 32-bit.

I have tried isntalling the packages via conda's default install feature, but the command fails even after adding the conda-forge channel.

Is it possible to work around this issue? Is manually installing the packages (not via pip) a viable option?

Comment: Why do you try to install with `pip` if you have `conda`? Shouldn't you be using `conda` to install things?

Comment: Ah I see, sorry as I have just started using conda. However, as I mentioned, the conda command also returns me an error.